# How to deploy a phantomjs node app on AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, aws-lambda, spookyjs

I threw together a small Lambda function together to crawl a website using the SpookyJS, CasperJS, and PhantomJS toolchain for headless browsing. The task is quite simple, and at some point a few months ago it was working in Lambda. I recently had to change a few things around and wanted to work on the project again, but started fresh and had trouble getting Lambda to run without erroring in any capacity. My question is **how can I run phantomjs in Lambda**?

The example code I am running is:

```
spooky.start('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spooky_the_Tuff_Little_Ghost');
spooky.then(function () {
    this.emit('hello', 'Hello, from ' + this.evaluate(function () {
        return document.title;
    }));
});
spooky.run();
```

The error I am getting in Lambda is:

```
{ [Error: Child terminated with non-zero exit code 1] details: { code: 1, signal: null } }
```

I have followed a variety of procedures to ensure everything is able to run on Lambda. Below is a long list of things I've attempted to diagnose:

1. Run locally using `node index.js` and confirm it is working
2. Upload package.json and the js file to an Amazon Linux EC2 instance for compilation as recommended for npm installation calls and described [here](http://www.kimgunnarsson.se/compile-node-module-binaries-for-aws-lambda/)
3. Run `npm install` on the ec2 instance, and again run `node index.js` to ensure the correct output
4. zip everything up, and deploy to AWS using the cli

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "lambda-spooky-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "casperjs": "^1.1.3",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.10",
    "spooky": "^0.2.5"
  }
}
```

I have also attempted the following (most also working locally, and on the AWS EC2 instance, but with the same error on Lambda:

1. Trying the non -prebuilt version of phantom
2. Ensuring casperjs and phantomjs are accessible from the path with `process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + '/node_modules/.bin';
   console.log( 'PATH: ' + process.env.PATH );`
3. Inspecting spawn calls by wrapping child_process's `.spawn()` call, and got the following:

   ```
   { '0': 'casperjs',
     '1': 
      [ '/var/task/node_modules/spooky/lib/bootstrap.js',
        '--transport=http',
        '--command=casperjs',
        '--port=8081',
        '--spooky_lib=/var/task/node_modules/spooky/lib/../',
        '--spawnOptions=[object Object]' ],
     '2': {} }
   ```
4. Calling `.exec('casperjs')` and `.exec('phantomjs --version')` directly, confirming it works locally and on EC2, but gets the following error in Lambda. The command:

   ```
   `require('child_process').exec('casperjs', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   if (error) { console.error('error: ' + error); }
      console.log('out: ' + stdout);
      console.log('err: ' + stderr);
   });
   ```

*both* with the following result:

```
err: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c casperjs
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/lib/phantomjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs:16:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)

2016-08-07T15:36:37.349Z    b9a1b509-5cb4-11e6-ae82-256a0a2817b9    sout: 
2016-08-07T15:36:37.349Z    b9a1b509-5cb4-11e6-ae82-256a0a2817b9    serr: module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/lib/phantomjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/.bin/phantomjs:16:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue to be that including the `node_modules/.bin` in the path works on both local and ec2 machines because those files simply point to the action `/bin` folders in each respective library. This breaks if calls within those files use relative paths. The issue:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-32-87 .bin]$ ls -lrt
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 35 Aug  7 00:52 phantomjs -> ../phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 24 Aug  7 00:52 casperjs -> ../casperjs/bin/casperjs
```

I worked around this by adding each library's respective bin to the lambda path in the Lambda handler function:

```
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] 
        + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + '/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin'
        + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + '/node_modules/casperjs/bin';
```

And this will now run phantom, casper, and spooky correctly in Lambda.

Comment: In case anyone else finds this and is suffering a similar problem. Even after the above, I was still suffering from "Child terminated with non-zero exit code 1" Turns out, I had to go into the casperjs directory under node_modules and run npm_update, as it was missing dependencies that were not being sourced properly from the parent